# URL Re-Write using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I am working on ASP.NET website (VS 2010, Framework 4.0).

How can I rewrite the URL of a page using C#? Is there any third party tools available? Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: [check] ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx)

Comment: No luck from whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: I am not trying for URL re write in web.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the current path
    string CurrentURL = Request.Url.ToString();
     // Condition
    if (CurrentURL.Contains("HtmlResponce.aspx"))
    {
        HttpContext MyContext = HttpContext.Current;

        // Re write here
        MyContext.RewritePath("testPage.aspx");
    }
}
```

I tried this piece of code in Global.asax. It works for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you are on IIS 7.x, you're better off with URL-Rewriting Module 2.0, from here: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/664/using-url-rewrite-module-20/

The link posted above points to the "old" technique, used back in the days of IIS6.

The new option for IIS 7.x is much simpler and more convenient.